# VS2010 fails on linking a lib that it's supposed to build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I'm having troubles with VS2010 when trying to build my DLL project.
The DLL in itself is pretty well generated, but the `.lib` file I need to link with other dependant projects fails.

I have a classic `__declspec(dllexport)` and everything, don't worry about that, the build works perfectly in debug mode. I only have this issue in Release mode, but I don't hink I messed up with my settings (they're almost default).

Here's the output error I get (unresolved extern symbol) :

```
Erreur  274 error LNK1120: 1 externes non résolus   \Release\Engine.lib Engine
Erreur  273 error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu App   LINK    Engine
```

For sure Visual Studio can't find this file: It's supposed to generate it!

I thought I had found a solution in [Dll project doesn't build as Linker not able to find the same named .lib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647005/dll-project-doesnt-build-as-linker-not-able-to-find-the-same-named-lib-file)
 (same problem) but I didn't understand how the answer was solving anything.

Has anyone ever had this issue and found a way to avoid it?

Comment: Could it be possible, that the *.lib is actually built, but saved in another folder?

Comment: The error message isn't saying what you think - it is telling you which file it was trying to build, and giving you the name of a *symbol* it couldn't find in any of the object files or libraries it linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the build works perfectly in debug mode. I only have this issue in
>   Release mode

Open up your .vcxproj file and check that your dependencies are consistent between debug and release builds, e.g., external libraries, additional include paths, etc. When this happens to me it's usually because I added something my debug configuration and forgot to make a similar change for release.

Comment: There was indeed a difference between the two configurations that I didn't spot using the properties of the project under VS. For thoses who are interested in what was the difference, I had this line in Release and not in Debug : <AdditionalOptions>/EXPORT:App %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>   thank you very much for your help !